# How can I programmatically make a control added to a form, public?

Tags: c#, winforms

For exampple

```
    Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
    frm1.Controls.Add(tb);
```

now I can't say `frm1.tb`   because tb is not public.

If i'd drawn the textbox then I could go to the properties window and set the modifier to public. So, I know how to do it in the GUI.

But how can I do it programmatically?

**Added Clarification**

Some have suggested alternatives to frm.tb, that wasn't what I was looking for.

I'll elaborate.

Consider this winforms program. It has two forms. Form1 and FormX

This is FormX

[image]

Form1 has just this code in its load

```
    FormX frmx = new FormX();
    frmx.drawnTextBox.Text = "blah"; //works
    TextBox programmaticallyMadeTextbox = new TextBox();

    frmx.Controls.Add(programmaticallyMadeTextbox);
    frmx.Show();
    frmx.programmaticallyMadeTextbox.Text = "asdf"; // does not compile
    // can't say frm1.programmaticallyMadeTextbox.Text="asdf"
    // why not?
    // I suppose because programmaticallyMadeTextbox is not public
    // how can I make it public like my drawnTextBox is public?
```

It is meant to add a textbox to FormX, and set the textbox's text property the same way I can do with the drawnTextBox.

The reason why I can do that with drawnTextBox, is that I set the modifier property to public.  I'd like to somehow do that with the textbox I made programmatically.

Comment: I assume you're trying to access the form in another method but can't? Declare it above and outside of the method scope.

Comment: You can always give the textbox a name and then use *theForm.Controls.Find(theTextBoxName, false);*

Comment: It is a local variable now, you can easily move it and make it a member of your class.  So it becomes `this.tb`.   Pick a better name.  That does not make it a member of the Form1 class of course.  Doesn't matter, that class doesn't know beans about it anyway.  You have to set it back to null when the form is closed, add an event handler for frm1.FormClosed.

Comment: @prospector No i'm not. I've never had any issue accessing a form

Comment: @Gusman see my elaboration. I don't see why I should have to do that.  I don't have to do that with my drawn textbox (where I could set the modifier to public in the Visual Studio GUI)

Comment: It's just another way to achieve the same result, think a case where you have a lot of textboxes, it's easy to search them on the Controls collection than creating properties to acces them. But anyway, there are multiple methods to do it, it's just another way.

Answer (score 4):

Usually I do this when adding the controls dynamically, give them a (proper)**name** and find the control from the collection when it is needed.

```
TextBox textbox = new TextBox();
// other properties
textbox.Name = "newtextbox";  // Any unique name
form1.Controls.Add(textbox);
```

Now you could access the elements.

```
var textbox = Controls.OfType(TextBox)().FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Name == "newtextbox");

if(textbox != null)
{
    // access element.
}
```

Comment: See my updated question, Why is it that `frmx.programmaticallyMadeTextbox.Text = "asdf"; `  does not work   Whereas `frmx.drawnTextBox.Text = "blah";` does work ?

Answer (score -1):

You could add this line to the `Form1` class in the `Form1.cs` file.

```
public TextBox tb;
```

and change your example to

```
Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
frm1.tb = new TextBox();
frm1.Controls.Add(frm1.tb);
```

or maybe you could get access to your `TextBox` using `frm1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Single()` or `frm1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().First()` or `frm1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Last()`.